# Format a date time string

Tags: asp-classic, datepart

Im having a problem formatting a datetime field in ASP Classic.
The format I need is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
this is my code so far:

```
changeToDate = cdate(Request.Form("datepicker")&" "&Request.Form("timepicker")) 

dateTime = DatePart("d", changeToDate)&"-"&DatePart("m", changeToDate)&_
           "-"&DatePart("yyyy", changeToDate)&" "&DatePart("hh", changeToDate)&":"&_
           DatePart("mi", changeToDate)&":00"
```

but this gives me a invalid procedure call datepart exception. I'm kind of stuck on this.

Not sure if it matters or not but I am doing this so that I can insert the datetime into the database. when i just use the cdate function I get the following error:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
This is what my query looks like with just the cdate function called:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(Client ,Campaign ,Location ,CardCode ,Created ,Message ,Rating ,Info ,mobile ,DataMessage ) VALUES (117,227,1487,'NJPNUYX','10/07/2013 9:10:00 a.m.','NJPNUYX 4 safda',4,'safda','0215833650','0223232345')
```

Comment: could you please tell us exactly where the exception is thrown and what the error message says??

Comment: I suspect that this is in a build up to passing the date to a database - if this is the case, please stop doing this - pass the date across in a parameter, **as a date** and let ADO/the database system work out how to translate VB dates into the database server's representation. Formatting dates as strings is one of the largest sources of bugs.

Comment: @ damien_the_unbeliever, yes it is to put it into the database. I did try to insert it with just after the cdate function but got an error for it saying it was the wrong format which is why i am trying to convert it to the right format.

Comment: As I said, in that case, you ought to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675869(v=vs.85).aspx) - in this way, you can pass it across as a *date* rather than as a string. It's you forcing things into a string that is *causing* the formatting issue in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the incorrect parameters in your hour and minute DatePart calls.

According to MSDN you need to use the following:

- hour - h (instead of hh)
- minute - n (instead of mi)

Change:

```
DatePart("hh", changeToDate) & ":" & DatePart("mi", changeToDate)
```

to

```
DatePart("h", changeToDate) & ":" & DatePart("n", changeToDate)
```

For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529%28v=vs.84%29.aspx